# JavaScript: Chrome incorrectly compares strings

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

**Can anybody explain is it a bug in Chrome or I incorrectly compare strings?**

Sort method in Chrome provides odd (at least for me) result. 
I do the following:

```
var a = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "a", "b", "c"]

a.sort((i1,i2)=>i1>i2)

["7", "c", "b", "a", "9", "8", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1"]
```

Firefox gives expected result:

```
["c", "b", "a", "9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3","2","1"]
```

Answer (score 5):

It's a bug in your `sort` callback, not the JavaScript engine.

The callback must return a **number**, not a boolean:

- `0` if the arguments are equivalent
- `<0` if the first argument is "less than" the second
- `>0` if the second argument is "less than" the first

`localeCompare` is handy for getting a correct return value if you want the array in ascending order by string comparison in the natural ordering. In your case, though, you want the opposite, so negate it:

```js
var a = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "a", "b", "c"]
a.sort((i1, i2) => -i1.localeCompare(i2));
console.log(a);
```

...or (doh) just do `i2.localeCompare(i1)` instead.

Comment: @evolutionxbox: :-)

Comment: I thought it was some secret knowledge that I didn't know =P

Answer (score 2):

Your sort comparator function does not follow the contract. A sort comparator should return a negative number if the first parameter should sort before the second, a positive number if the second should sort before the first, and 0 if the parameters are already in acceptable order.

Your function returns a boolean, which will be interpreted as either `0` or `1`. That means that when the sort operation calls it with the same two values in different order, the function may return conflicting results.

Consider two values in the list, "a" and "b".  If the sort operation invokes your callback like this:

```
var ordering = yourCallback("a", "b"); // not really how it looks of course
```

then your callback will return `0`, and the sort function will interpret that as meaning that the two values are already in order.  If it later calls the function like *this*:

```
var ordering = yourCallback("b", "a");
```

it'll get `1`. That's inconsistent with the first result for the same two parameters.

The spec for the language does not stipulate what algorithm is to be used for the implementation of `.sort()`, and the JavaScript runtimes in Firefox and Chrome are definitely different in the details of how they respond to aberrant sort comparator functions.